# Partitioning in Oracle using custom functions

Tags: oracle, scalability, partition

I'm trying to partition my table using the ID column such that all even ID's should go in partition_1 and odd ID's should go in partition_2. The only closest thing that met my needs was `virtual columns`.

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
 id       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
 mod_id AS (MOD(id, 2))
);
PARTITION BY RANGE (mod_id)
(
 PARTITION mod_id VALUES LESS THAN(1),
 PARTITION mod_id VALUES LESS THAN(2),
)
```

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Should be fine, does it not work as expected?

Comment: this is my first time partitioning, how do I know the partition in which a record resides?

Comment: things aren't bad, but while inserting i have to specify all the columns (except the virtual column).

Comment: This seems like an unusual way to partition.  What are you trying to achieve with this partitioning scheme?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MOD function to calculate mod_id, your column would have only 2 values (0 & 1),
In that case you can go with LIST partition as below.

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
 id       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
 mod_id AS (MOD(id, 2))
)
PARTITION BY LIST (mod_id)
      (PARTITION mod_id0 VALUES (0),
       PARTITION mod_id1 VALUES (1));
```

It is certain that records with odd id will to partition mod_id1 and even into mod_id0.
You can verify it using below query:
`select * from sales partition (mod_id1);`